# Multiple layer of inheritance C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have a base resource that contains pure virtual functions like load and unload. I have then a class inheritent from this class and be AudioResource and have virtual functions aka like play and stop. I then in inherent from this class and have a class called BassAResource.

Lets imagine I have returned a type of type Resource* then I want to type cast it to AudioResource and call the load functions, and let the class that it actually is handle that but i keep getting problems saying that it is a pure virtual function within AudioResource =s

```
class Resource
{
    public:
        Resource();
        Resource(std::string filename,unsigned int scope, RESOURCE_TYPE type);
        virtual ~Resource();
        virtual void load() = 0;
        virtual void unload() = 0;


class AudioResource : public Resource
{
    public:
        AudioResource(std::string filename, unsigned int scope, RESOURCE_TYPE type, AUDIO_T Atype);
        virtual void load() = 0;
        virtual void unload() = 0;
        virtual void play() = 0;
        virtual void pause() = 0;
        virtual void stop() = 0;

class BASSAResource : public AudioResource
{
    public:
        ~BASSAResource();
        virtual void load();
        virtual void unload();
        virtual void play();
        virtual void pause();
        virtual void stop();
```

Comment: You need a better source code excerpt. The class definitions you included are incomplete (all 3 missing the closing curly brace and semi colon), and you haven't included any code that is trying to call the load function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot construct an 'AudioResource' as it has undefined methods.  I'll assume you're returning a 'BASSAResource' that has been cast to a Resource pointer.  Let me pseudo code to see if I get your meaning

```
Resource *myFunc() {
   BASSAResource *resource = new BASSAResource();
   return (Resource*)resource;
}

void myMain() {
   Resource *resource = myFunc();
   AudioResource *audio = (AudioResource*) resource;
   audio->load();
}
```

This should work fine - in fact why cast to AudioResource since load is defined as an abstract method in your Resource class. But if you wanted to 'play', this cast would be required.  Again, you cannot construct using 'new AudioResource()' due to the fact that you have an abstract method which must first be implemented.

Also, be very careful to make all destructors virtual.  Your ~BASSAResource is not virtual, and this will cause problems for you.

Comment: There is no inherent problem with not having a virtual destructor on a class, and suggesting someone should always have one without explaining when it is important is not useful. Virtual destructors only useful if your class (or some future child class) will do important work in the destructor that needs to happen even when a derived class is what is being destructed. That is often, but isn't always.

Comment: Always declare destructors as virtual.  They will not behave as expected if you do not.  This leads to silent memory leaks and clean-up problems.  There is no justifiable reason to not do this.

Comment: @AndrewKhosravian: a virtual destructor is required when you delete objects through base class pointers (e.g. `Base*base=new Derived; delete base;`.  However, casting to a base class pointer is so common in inheritance scenarios that if you have a virtual method, you should probably also define a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Kieveli: there are obviously reasons not to define a virtual destructor, or else this would not be an option (or it would at least be the default behavior).  One key reason not to add a virtual destructor is to define a POD type.  Note that many standard library types don't have a virtual destructor, including `std::string`, `std::vector` and other containers.

Comment: Thanks for wording that more clearly than the mess I produced André.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual inheritance only works with pointers (you have to reference the object, not the type).  Instead, cast it to type AudioResource* and treat it as a pointer (or use a smart pointer).

Comment: I am doing this :AudioResource* temp = (AudioResource*)(AudioManager::getInstance()->get("Song1.mp3"));
The get function returns type of Resource then i type cast to an AudioResource I am not sure if this is what you meant?

Comment: what is the line you get an error at?  because that looks like a valid line.